# Python Reading and writing binary

Tags: python, binary, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write individual bits to a text file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205487/how-to-write-individual-bits-to-a-text-file-in-python)

I have been searching, trying to find a way to simply read and write bits to/from a file. Most of the things I have found have just showed ways to convert characters to binary. such as:

```
    >>> byte = 'a'
    >>> byte = ord(byte)
    >>> byte = bin(byte)
    >>> print byte
    '0b1100001'
```

This isn't what I want. I am looking to manipulate the actual binary in the file. I dont want to use extra modules, just standard python 2.7. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yea i saw this and it seemed similar but im looking for a simpler explanation maybe and a clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

open files in binary mode, using `'r+b'`:

```
>>> f=open('data.txt','wb')
>>> f.write('abcd')
>>> f.close()
>>> f=open('data.txt','rb')
>>> [bin(ord(x)) for x in f.read(4)]        #read(4) to read 4 bytes
['0b1100001', '0b1100010', '0b1100011', '0b1100100']
>>>
```

Comment: not sure about python 2.7 but in python 3.x you can do `f.write(b'1100001')`