# Writing bits (from a bit string) to create a binary file in python

Tags: python, binary-data, bitstring

I am new to python. Here is what I am struggling to implement. 
I have a very long bit string "1010101010101011111010101010111100001101010101011 ... ".
I want to write this as bits and create a binary file using python.
(Later I want disassemble this using IDA, this is not important for this question).

Is there any way I can write to a file at bit level (as binary)? Or do I have to convert it to bytes first and then write byte by byte? What is the best approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a sequence of bits to a file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666947/passing-a-sequence-of-bits-to-a-file-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to convert it to bytes first and then write those bytes to a file.  Working on a per byte basis is probably also the best idea to keep control over the ordering of your bytes (big vs. little endian), etc.

You can use `int("10101110", 2)` to easily convert a bit string to a numeric value.  Then use a `bytearray` to create a sequence of all your byte values.  The result will look something like this:

```py
s = "1010101010101011111010101010111100001101010101011"
i = 0
buffer = bytearray()
while i < len(s):
    buffer.append( int(s[i:i+8], 2) )
    i += 8

# now write your buffer to a file
with open(my_file, 'bw') as f:
    f.write(buffer)
```